# Auditoria por columnas

Tags: c#

Buen dia. Estoy trabajando con una **arquitectura en capas** con **.net Core 3.1**. En la capa de apis esta IdentityDbContext y en la capa de Infraesructura tengo un DataContext que hereda de DbContext. Como se podria hacer una auditoria por columnas ya que tengo dos contextos y la capa inferior ni se entera cual es el usuario login, no asi con la capa de las Apis. Como puedo llegar de una forma generica a realizar una auditoria, asi todas mis entidades tengan  CreatedByUser, CreatedDate, ModifiedByUser, ModifiedDate, y al realizar una operacion se vaya haciendo la auditoria

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tu pregunta puede llegar a estar basada en opiniones.. fijate de que quede claro que exista una respuesta valida...

Comment: tenes que agregar tu codigo, y deberias usar una interfaces para que todos modelos hereden esos metodos.